# Question about solutions of linear system

Tags: homework-and-exercises, mathematics, linear-algebra, linear-systems

I've just started studying linear algebra.

I had a question while studying an example.

I'm gonna explain the problem.

$$\\$$
$$\\$$

Augmented matrix for a linear system in the unknowns x, y and z is

$$
  \left[\begin{array}{rrr|r}
    1 & 0 & 3 & -1 \\
    0 & 1 & -4 & 2 \\
    0 & 0 & 0 & 0
  \end{array}\right]
$$
$
\\
\\
$

The linear system corresponding to the augmented matrix is

$$ x + 3z = -1 \\
  y - 4z = 2 $$

As you all know, if you apply a parametric equation to the above equations, you can obtain a general solution like this.

$$ x = -1 -3t,\, y = 2 + 4t, \,z = t$$

But from what I learned, geometrically, the solution of the linear system is the intersection of each graph.

If we rewrite the above equations for z

$$ z = -{1 \over 3}x - {1 \over 3} \\
   z = {1 \over 4}y - {1 \over 2}
$$

It seems that these linear equations' graphs go through different planes (xz-plane, yz-plane) and never intersect.

So my question is, how can there be solutions when the graphs drawn by linear equations don't make a intersection geometrically?

I guess I have a misunderstanding. I'd like someone to point this out.

Comment: That's because you have 3 variables and only two equation.